# Warning : Array to string conversion in

Tags: php

Este es un error de **PHP** que siempre que me lo topo me quita mucho tiempo **¿Alguien me lo puede explicar?**. Mira tengo la siguiente sentencia:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE user='$userD' and tokenUser='$tokenD'";
$resultado2 =mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
$datos2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2);

echo($datos2);
```

Todo bien. La sentencia básicamente esta solicitando una **"ID"** y esa **"ID"** en este caso es un **"1"** y cuando hago el "echo" me sale el **warning** (Todo bien, espera...)

Si hago el **var_dump** me dice que el resultado es este:

**array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1"**  (Osea que en efecto ahí esta ese **"1"** **¡PERO YO SOLAMENTE NECESITO EL "1"!**  ¿No se si me explico osea **NO NECESITO todo esto de: **array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1)**

///

**Mi pregunta es:**

¿Cómo hago para que la consulta **me devuelva solamente el valor 1** (Para así meterlo en una **$variable** y "llevarmelo"? Ya que este **warning** siempre me termina quitando tiempo.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc devuelve un array asociativo siempre, de ahí esa estructura que ves con el var_dump.  Si quieres tratar con solo esa clave **id** puedes encontrarlo con `echo $datos2['id'];` donde le pides a la variable de array asociativo denominada `$datos2` que te muestre su clave `id` directamente.

Comment: @masterguru Te agradezco. Si saco el valor de esta manera $datos2['id'] y se lo asigno a una $variable ¿No tendré problemas?. Lo menciono porque **ESE VALOR de "ID"** lo estoy sacando en un archivo **.php** pero lo tengo que enviar a través de un formulario para recogerlo por **POST** en otro archivo **.php**

Comment: Claro, puedes hacer lo que quieras con el después. Piensa que cuando realizas cualquier consulta con mysqli o PDO siempre te va a devolver o bien un array o bien un objeto, pero nunca el valor directo de la consulta, por lo tanto siempre vas a tener que tratarlo como tal (o sea, como array o como objeto) para hacer tus asignaciones o lo que necesites despues, como por ejemplo recorrer un resultado de una consulta de varias filas en un bucle, o si se trata de una sola fila pues directamente tal como has hecho sin bucle.

Comment: Fíjate la cantidad de métodos que tienes para manejar el resultado de una consulta com mysqli en la tabla de contenidos de [este enlace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php) del manual de PHP.  Si vas investigándolos todos verás que siempre hay un array o un objeto por medio aunque tengas una query simple que tan solo te devuelva un valor de una columna de una tabla, y al principio cuesta de entender, pero con la práctica te acotumbrarás.